# Is 時間がありますか unnatural?

Tags: particles

I asked a few native speakers about which phrase was more natural in a situation where I ask a friend if they had time:

> 時間がありますか？

or

> 時間はありますか？

They all chose the latter. So is the former unnatural? In what situations would you use it in?

Comment: I have no supporting study to back up this claim. I posit that the transition from the k-sound from 間 to the g-sound from が (two velar sounds), is less smooth than the transition from 間 to the w-sound from は. I suppose a way to check this is to measure the は・が preference of deaf/mute Japanese, and compare it to the preference for non-deaf/mute.

Comment: @Flaw It's exactly the same situation with all 「○○（が／は）ありますか？」 sentences (i.e., は is almost unilaterally the correct choice for question sentences). In addition, 「時間があります。」 is just fine (especially when there's some extra qualifier or explicit topic in the sentence), despite the same //kanga// sequence. So, I really don't think it's a phonological phenomenon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm amused to read all of your native Japanese speaking friends chose 時間はあります. To me 時間があります and 時間はあります sound the same, and look interchangeable as a postpositional particle - は、が following the subject..

If I was asked which of が and は I would choose in the following examples, I would choose

> バッテリーの交換は３０分かかります。(お待ちいただく)時間**は**ありますか？
>
> 開宴まで５分です。トイレに行く時間**は**ありますか？
>
> もう６０歳だ。残された時間**は**ない
>
> まだ十分考える時間**が**ある
>
> くだくだ言っている時間**は**ない

But it doesn’t mean the other option would be grammatically wrong.

Frankly I don’t know why I chose them this way. It might be just intuitive for me, and it is a matter of taste at best. I don’t think the choice of は and が makes any significant difference in meaning or grammaticality in most cases.

Comment: It might be slightly confusing since in "If I was asked which of が and は I would choose in the following examples", が is the former and は is the latter. But in the subsequent examples, the order is reversed such that は is the former and が is the latter. There is confusion in the closing statement "Frankly I don’t know why I chose the former than the latter".

Comment: `Flaw. Regarding the closing statement, "Frankly I don’t know why I chose the former than the latter,".I said so because I can't offer grammatical justifications about my choice, as I'm not academic grammarian.  I'm  just talking based on my 83 years of experience of living as a Japanese who is interested in reading and intuition.

Comment: I did not mean the conclusion itself was confusing. I was referring to the possible mix-up of what "former" and "latter" refers to. It looks like that has been cleared up in an edit, so the confusion has been resolved.

Answer (score 4):

As a native speaker, I would also definitely choose your ***second*** sentence using 「**は**」 if you just asked me:

> "Which phrase is more natural in a situation where I ask a friend if they had time?"

without giving any more specific information.  In other words, the ***exact context***. What is the situation in which you are asking this friend if s/he has time?  What exactly did you and/or s/he say immediately before you uttered the sentence 「時間（　）ありますか？」, etc.?

Japanese is an ***extremely*** contextual language; Context is king. And believe me, that is still an understatement.

With over three decades of experience with Japanese-learners, I know well that their "favorite" subject marker is 「が」 for the reasons I have yet to understand to be honest.  Many use it as if it were the default option.

You need a good reason to use 「が」 over 「は」, but the question **"Do you have time?"** is so generic in nature that choosing to use 「が」 is not only fairly unnatural but is also highly unjustifiable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not technically impossible to use 時間が… for questions (unlike sentences of statement that represent speaker's judgement) but it may sound like you suspect that they have time. Usually, you use a sentence that contains some topic when you ask people and expect them to reply, for them to follow the topic you have staked.

Answer (score 0):

One option that might be overlooked is to *omit* the particle, as opposed to choosing "は" or "が". In this case, it would sound much closer to "は" than "が".

Personally, I would go with this third option, in most cases.

Nonetheless, I concur that [context really is important when discussing Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30795/11830). There are cases when one would sound correct, and the other incorrect and vice versa.

> In what situations would you use [the former] in?

When the subject is made clear to be someone other than the listener.