# Do we really have to change particles (usually が into は) in negative and interrogative sentences?

Tags: particles, negation, na-adjectives, は-and-が, interrogatives

Which alternatives sound more natural?

> 1.1 - その本**は**読めない。
> 1.2 - その本**が**読めない。
>
> 2.1 - ゴルフ**は**上手じゃない。
> 2.2 - ゴルフ**が**上手じゃない
>
> 3.1 - この映画**は**見たくない。
> 3.2 - この映画**が**見たくない。
> 3.3 - この映画**を**見たくない。
>
> 4.1 - 日本語**は**分からない。
> 4.2 - 日本語**が**分からない。
>
> 5.1 - 魚**は**好きじゃない。
> 5.2 - 魚**が**好きじゃない。
>
> 6.1 - ビール**は**ありますか？
> 6.2 - ビール**が**ありますか？

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30787/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38445/7810

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in general, you should mark something as a topic using は, especially in negative sentences and questions. You should use は in all of your short example sentences.

Of course there are well-known exceptions:

- In subordinate clauses (including relative clauses), が can be used.

  > - この本**が**読めないなら、もっと簡単な本があります。
  > - 日本語**が**分からない人
- If there is already another topic marked with は, you don't have to use it twice.

  > - 私**は**この本**が**読めない。
  > - 彼**は**日本語**が**分からない。
- If "exhaustive-listing が" is intended, が has to be used.

  > - 英語ではなく、日本語**が**分からない。
  >     It's *Japanese* that I don't understand, not *English*.

Comment: Related: 彼は今日は休みです。